# Sketch the graph of the polynomial function $P(x)= x(x-3)(x+2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Sketch the graph of the polynomial function. Make sure your graph shows all the intercepts and exhibits the proper end behavior.

$$P(x) = x(x-3)(x+2) $$

Should I ignore $x=0$ as a value?

Answer (score 1):

We need to graph the function
$$P(x)=x(x-3)(x+2)$$
We know that it approaches $-\infty$ on the left and $\infty$ on the right (coefficient of the $x^3$ term is positive). We also know that there will be three $x$-intercepts: one at $0$, one at $3$, and one at $-2$. The $y$-intercept can be calculated by letting $x=0$.
$$0(0-3)(0-2)=0$$
The $y$-intercept is $0$.

We know that our function is going to head up from the left, pass through the $x$-axis at $-2$, go up some more, then "turn" and head downward. Now it passes through the $x$-axis at $0$, goes down some more, then "turn" and head back up. Then it will pass through the $x$-axis at $3$, then go up all the way to $\infty$.

The graph should look something like this:

[image: Graph]

The op wanted a sign diagram, so here it is:

[image: Sign Diagram]

Comment: Thanks so much. I think I need help setting up the sign diagram. I will give it another shot.

Comment: @Prologue You can use my graph to set up the sign diagram. You draw a number line with the $x$-intercepts labeled on it. To the left of the $-2$, it is negative ($-$). Between $-2$ and $0$ it is positive ($+$). Between $0$ and $3$ it is negative ($-$). To the right of $3$ it is positive (+).

Comment: Can you show me a sign diagram. For some reason mine is positive in the negative infinity direction.

Comment: Forget it I got. I forgot to give the x variable a value.

Answer (score 0):

No, you should include it. $x=0$ is a root of the function, making it an $x$-intercept that they want you to to include. Since it's at $x=0$ (obviously) it is also a $y$-intercept (it's the origin after all), so it's doubly important for the things they want you to show.

Comment: So I include it in the sign diagram? I just put whatever test value there is right in the interval and take it's sign?

Comment: Your intervals have their ends at each of the roots. These are $-2, 0,$ and $3$. So yes, $x=0$ should be included as a boundary and you should test on either side of it to figure out whether the polynomial is positive or negative there.

Comment: So my intervals are (negative infinity, -2) (-2,0) (0,3) (3,infinity)?

Answer (score 0):

No of course not, if you want to sketch a curve you need to be mindful of the following aspects of a curve:

- The roots of the curve if it has any and can be easily found (for your polynomial it is pretty easy to know
- The y-intercept is also important if there is one
- All the asymptotes, be it vertical (easiest to spot when you have a rational function), horizontal, and oblique (if you have a rational function where the degree of the denominator is one more then the numerator)
- Max and min values (using differentiation and the sign chart that I am sure you learned)
- Points of inflection (seeing when the graph changes from concave to convex, using the second derivative of the function)

There might be other stuff I am forgetting about that might even make it easier to draw it, like if you are given a bound, if the function is periodic, if it is even or odd or neither. Anyways anything that can give you insight into the stuff I listed is important!

Comment: So my intervals are not (negative infinity, -2) (-2,0) (0,3) (3,infinity) for the sign diagram?